# Пауза перед запуском скрипта

Tags: javascript

проблема такая: есть скрипт,срабатывающий по нажатию кнопки, который добавляет новый `<select>` . Если уже добавлен хотя бы один `<select>`, скрипт должен задизейблить этот `<select>` и создать спрятанный `<input>` с его значением. При нажатие на кнопку несколько раз подряд, скрипт срабатывает некорректно, т.к. не успевает считывать элементы со страницы. Как создать задержку между вызовами скрипта? Я пробовал `setTimeout()`, но это не помогало, потому что скрипт вызывался с паузой не после СРАБАТЫВАНИЯ скрипта, а после НАЖАТИЯ на кнопку.

Comment: прочитайте про Event Loop

Comment: Было бы не плохо увидеть код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первым делом в скрипте ставите `button.disabled=true`. В конце скрипта - отменяете это `button.disabled=false`. Не нужны никакие паузы.

Comment: спасибо, помогло